# Header and Footer disappear when using docxtpl

Tags: python, python-docx

not sure why this is happening, but the below code does remove the header and footer from my document
any help appreciated?

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

tpl=DocxTemplate('test_files/csa_template_tpl.docx')

sd = tpl.new_subdoc()
p = sd.add_paragraph('This 1st insert')

sd2 = tpl.new_subdoc()
p = sd2.add_paragraph('This 2nd insert')

context1 = {
    'mysubdoc1' : sd,
    'mysubdoc2' : sd2,
    'cost' : '10,000',
    'project_description': 'facade upgrade',
    'site': 'Penrith',
    'sp': 'xxxxxxxx',
    'wo': '1',
    'contract_manager': 'Andrew Mate',
    'csa_no': '1',


}

tpl.render(context1)
tpl.save('test_files/csa_template.docx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, the library documentation mentions compatibility issues with new word document version, i reverted to "Maintain compatibility with previous versions of word" when saving.